# How would one go about making a large grid where you just define once how an element of it ought to behave?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

A bunch of tutorials that I have seen make a GridLayout, then copy and baste a button for every cell.
Let's say I want to make tic-tac-toe, but on a 6x6 grid. I'm not gonna copy and paste 36 buttons. Can you still use a pre-defined view for this, or do I have to create my own "TicTacToeBoard" view?

Answer (score 1):

You should never copy-paste code to repeat an action. Just use a loop. Presumably you want to be able to access and work with each of the 36 buttons, so it is most practical to create a 2D list of them as you're creating them. The List interface has a pseudo-constructor that takes a size parameter and a lambda parameter that is repeatedly called to create each item you want in the List. (It's a "pseudo-constructor" because interfaces can't actually have constructors. It's actually a factory function that looks like a constructor because it starts with a capital letter.)

Something like this:

```
lateinit var buttons: List<List<Button>>

// In onCreateView after you've inflated a layout and have a reference to your grid layout:

buttons = List(6) { 
    List(6) { 
        Button(requireContext()).also(gridLayout::addView)
    } 
}
```

I just put a basic Button constructor call, but you could customize it inside this lambda, or you could create one that you set up in XML using LayoutInflater. Defining in XML would be the easiest way to give it appropriate styling and layout parameters for the grid layout. It might look something like this:

```
buttons = List(6) { 
    List(6) { 
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tic_tac_toe_item, gridLayout, true)
    } 
}
```

Since they're in a 2D list, you can access them using `buttons[row][column]` where `row` and `column` are integers from 0 to 5.